# How to call a text_field based on tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I don't know if this is possible, but if a user creates a tag called mission-statement in a valuations form:

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, valuation: @valuation.tag_list.to_s.titleize %>
```

how can we make the `:name` of that valuation appear in the home page `:jumbotron`:

```
<% content_for :jumbotron do %>
      <h1>Mission</h1>
      <p>
        # Mission Statement Goes Here
        <% @valuation_mission.each do |valuation_mission| %>
          <%= valuation_mission.name %>
        <% end %>
      </p>
<% end %>
```

I assume we'd have to write a method in the pages_controller like I attempted:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
      @user = current_user
    if logged_in?
      @habits = current_user.habits
      @valuations = current_user.valuations
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
      @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
      @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
      @valuation_mission = current_user.valuations #We'd need to add .something to make this work?
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
   end
end
```

I'm using the acts-as-taggable-on gem, which I learned how to implement from here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `current_user.valuations` should return the list of all (can be empty!) Valuation record associated with the `current_user`

Comment: Okay cool I revised the question @MrYoshiji

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with the valuations of a user? You already get them by simply doing `current_user.valuations`. If you want to get all their names with a coma between each for example, then use `current_user.valuations.map(&:name).join(', ')`

Comment: I'm trying to only pull valuations @MrYoshiji with the tag: mission-statement.

Comment: What does `current_user.valuations` returns? An array of strings? If yes then `current_user.valuations.select{ |tag| tag.match(/mission-statement/) }`

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji! You're on the right track except I get an `undefined method 'match' for #<Valuation:0x007f921ab002a8>`. In my migration I have this in regards to the tags: `create_table :tags do |t| t.string :name end`. Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
current_user.valuations.tagged_with('mission-statement')
```

Found in the documentation: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects